# Haskell function to generate prime numbers up to argument

Tags: haskell, primes

I made a function to generate a list of prime numbers using list comprehensions. Here it is:

```
let primes n = [x, x <- [2..n], length [y, y <- [2..x-1], mod x y == 0] == 0]
```

Is this a good approach? I am sure that there are much better ways of approaching this.

Comment: this doesn't work, unless the first `,`s in both lists are changed into `|`s; then it becomes one of the [one-liners](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers_miscellaneous#One-liners). `length [...] == 0` is better written`null [...]` which can stop early. the approach is good, simplicity- and clarity-wise. complexity- and speed-wise, not so much. you could also write it without the upper limit, as `[x | x <- [2..], null [y | y <- [2..x-1], rem x y==0]]`. it is also good for showing the generated primes slower and slower on the screen, so they don't turn into a blur. :)